# How to justify the statement that a graph is connected?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness

> Is the graph connected? Justify.

Because there is a path connecting all pairs of vertices, this graph is therefore connected?

Is that right?

[image: graph]

Comment: It's even totally connected. Every possible edge exists.

Comment: @AlexR, a *complete* graph

Comment: what are the numbers ?

Answer (score 2):

If it were disconnected, you could find two vertices with no path between them.  But every vertex is incident to every other vertex, so that isn't possible.